# ballistic problem

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables, uniform-distribution

A projectile is launched at an angle $θ$ with respect to the surface with velocity $v_0$ (deterministic). If the angle of inclination is a uniform random variable on $[0,π/2]$, calculate the function distribution of the variable $R$ defined as the point of impact of the projectile on the ground, measured from the origin. Also calculate the expectation.

$\textbf{Hint}$: Remember that the equations of motion are given by:
$$x(t)=x_{0}+\left(v_{0} \cos \theta\right) t, \quad y(t)=y_{0}+\left(v_{0} \operatorname{sen} \theta\right) t-\frac{1}{2} g t^{2} .$$

The first thing I did was determine the distance between the origin and the drop point, which is $R(\theta)=v_{0}\cos(\theta)t=(2/g)v_{0}^{2}\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)=(v_{0}^{2}/g)\sin(2\theta)$. The latter, since at the point of impact the height is $0$, then $y_{0}+\left(v_{0} \operatorname{sen} \theta\right) t-\frac{1}{2} g t^{2}=0$. Then the greatest distance is reached in $\theta=\pi/4$, so $R(\theta)\in [0,v_{0}^2/g]$. Thus obtaining that the distribution function of $R$ is:
$$F_{R}(r)=\mathbb{P}(R\leq r)=\mathbb{P}\left(\frac{v_{0}^2\sin(2\theta)}{g}\leq r\right)=\mathbb{P}\left(\theta\leq \frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{gr}{v_{0}^2}\right)}{2}\right)=\frac{2}{\pi}\cdot\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{gr}{v_{0}^2}\right)}{2}=\frac{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{gr}{v_{0}^2}\right)}{\pi}$$
That is, the density function is:
$$f_{R}(r)=\frac{dF_{R}(r)}{dr}=\frac{g}{\pi\sqrt{v_{0}^4-g^{2}r^{2}}}, r\in [0,v_{0}^2/g]$$
But when I integrate the density function I don't get 1. What part is wrong?

Comment: ummm... just normalize it, perhaps?

Comment: Didn't you forget that there are two possibilities for $\sin (2\theta) \leq \cdots$ You may either have $\theta$ close to $0$ or $\theta$ close to $\pi/2$. As you noted, $R(\theta)$ has a maximum at $\theta= \pi/4$.

Answer (score 1):

$\sin(2\theta)$ is not one-to-one over $[0, \pi/2]$. So $P[\frac{v_0^2 \sin(2\theta)}{g} \leq r] \neq P[\theta \leq \frac{\arcsin(\frac{gr}{v_0^2})}{2}]$. Instead
\begin{align*}
P\Big[\frac{v_0^2 \sin(2\theta)}{g} \leq r\Big] &= P\Big[\theta \leq \frac{\arcsin(\frac{gr}{v_0^2})}{2}\Big] + P\Big[\frac{\arcsin(\pi - \frac{gr}{v_0^2})}{2} \leq \theta\Big] \\
&= 2 \times \frac{2}{\pi}\frac{\arcsin(\frac{gr}{v_0^2})}{2} = \frac{2\arcsin(\frac{gr}{v_0^2})}{\pi}
\end{align*} for $r \in [0, v_0^2/g]$.

Comment: ok, i understand now, thanks.

Comment: @Nicolas you can accept the answer to close the question

Comment: Could it also be done for $\theta$ between $0$ and $\pi/4$ and multiply the density function by 2?

Comment: @Nicolas on $[0, \pi/4]$ $\sin(2\theta)$ **is** one-to-one. So $[\frac{v_0^2 \sin(2\theta)}{g} \leq r] = P[\theta \leq \frac{\arcsin(\frac{gr}{v_0^2})}{2}]$ is in fact true for that setup.

Comment: Then  the expected value is: $E(R)=\int_{0}^{v_{0}^2/g}\frac{2gr}{\pi\sqrt{v_{0}^4-g^2r^2}}=\frac{2v_{0}^2}{g\pi}$